# Create new app in getstream.io with nodejs in multi tenancy

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

following case:
I want to use getstream.io for my multi-tenancy application (with single instances architecture). Now I wonder if there is a way to create new apps in stream.io programmatically so that I do not have to create a new app for each instance manually? Has anyone experience with that?

Docs and search here have not provided me with sufficient information.

Comment: Good questions on Stack Overflow include an attempt to answer your own question. You should be specific about what the outcome you want is, what you have tried so far, what outcome you have gotten, and where you are stuck. Questions that are very open ended like this tend to be closed or downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream doesn't have API access for any admin functions (app creation, feed group creation, data deletion, etc). Most organizations will have a single app and either use different feed groups for different tenants. You could also have the same feed groups but keep track of the tenants in your feed names.